# Convert varchar with format d.m.yyyy to smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have `varchar` column with values in the format `d.m.yyyy` so the date could be 2.2.2014 or 11.11.2014

I need to update a `smalldatetime` column from this `varchar` column.

All I tried was ended with error message:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you show us the sql you're using to convert? Also, look at the source data for exceptional rows with malformed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working solution ...

```
UPDATE tTable
SET dDate = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, vDate, 104), 20)
```